# Laravel queues are not processing automatically until I run php artisan queue:work command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis, queue

I came through multiple solutions on stack overflow but no luck. It worked fine before 1 month but now a days it is not working.

I am using Ubuntu Os and nginx server. For queue driver I used redis
Here is my redis configuration in .env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

I also used supervisor to monitor and here is my configuration for supervisor

```
[program:worker-326242]
command=php7.4 /home/forge/myapp.com/artisan queue:work redis --sleep=10 --daemon --quiet --tries=3 --env=production --queue="default"

process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=forge
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/.forge/worker-326242.log
```

The problem is queue jobs are not executing automatically but it works when i run the command "php artisan queue:work"

Please ignore my poor english.
Any help will be appriciated

Comment: Did you check whether supervisor is running or not?

Comment: Your queue driver is redis, which mean you have to run the queue for it to work. Set it to sync and it will run automatically

Comment: @MajharulIslam Yes supervisor is running.

Comment: @JacobBrassington I have 3 similar sites. The rest of the sites are running fine with the above configuration. Sync is not a good idea as it executes jobs immediately.

Comment: Inside supervisorctl type `status` to check if all your processes are running. Type `fg [name of your process]` to display the output of your process, as you'd normally see when running the artisan command. Verify you don't see anything strange.

Comment: @MaartenVeerman Here is my output when I run "sudo supervisorctl status"
worker-326242:worker-326242_00   RUNNING   pid 1990955, uptime 0:00:08


But when i run the command as you suggested "sudo supervisorctl fg worker-326242:worker-326242_00"
then it shows following :
  Cannot automatically determine absolute path for '' given



In Capabilities.php line 19:

  Cannot automatically determine absolute path for '' given

Answer (score 0):

I was going through this same problem, and then I realized that my Shell file was without execution permission.

I decided to command:

```
chmod +x /file/path/supervisor-bash.sh
```

Hope this helps.